# Use SDK/API to join google meets meeting and record audio/video?

Tags: google-workspace, google-people-api, google-meet

So my use case is something like this. I need to join google meets meetings via automation(as a bot attendee) and get the audio/video and active speaker information in real time. In this case I will have the meeting uri that would be provided to me by the user and I need to join that meeting and perform the above scenarios. Can someone provide me with information on how this can be achieved? Does there exists sdk/apis for google meets which can be used to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do that with a CoWatchingClient in the [Google Meet Live Sharing SDK](https://developers.google.com/meet/live-sharing/guides/overview). But that SDK is in beta.

The alternative to an API is to reverse engineer the API. Since meet runs in a browser, you can take their JavaScript and de-obfuscate (there are [online tools](https://deobfuscate.io/)). Otherwise, you could use wireshark to watch packets back and forth or maybe Charles (a man in the middle tool) to ensure they're decrypted. Figure out what format they send the data so you can then use it.

Reverse engineering by decompiling may lead to legal trouble if you're making a commercial product. It may break if Google changes how things work.